# Can I deploy Web Application on intranet but for local Intranet user and database is on Cloud?

Tags: web-applications, clouddb

I have asked this question on other sites but could not get any answer which fits my situation: kindly help me in this regards.

Case:
Actually I want create a web server on Intranet and users (who do not have internet access) can connect to web server. on That web server asp.net application to be deployed, but database is on cloud.

I recently approached by a company that does not require internet for their user but they want their application and database to be on Cloud.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for an intranet site to connect to a database on the internet, as long as the server the site is hosted on has internet connectivity.

The actual implementation would depend on the database you choose to use of course.

Comment: Yes I agree but, If Application and Data Base are on cloud. how should i implement any Middle ware which should communicate with Cloud Hosted Application (on Internet) and users of Application on Intranet (don't have internet access.)